# A question about an Open Ball contained within another Open Ball

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Take two points $x_{1}, x_{2} \in X$ and $r_{1}, r_{2} \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$.

Let $B_{r_1}(x_1)$ and $B_{r_2}(x_2)$ be the open balls of radii $r_{1}$ and $r_{2}$ about the points $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$, respectively.

Suppose that $B_{r_1}(x_1) \subset B_{r_2}(x_2)$ (a proper subset), so that $B_{r_2}(x_2) \backslash B_{r_1}(x_1) \neq \emptyset$.

The goal is to prove that $r_1 < 2r_2$. I am going crazy trying to figure this one out.

$\ $

MY ATTEMPT AT THIS PROBLEM:

Fix any two points $u, v \in B_{r_2}(x_2) \backslash B_{r_1}(x_1)$, which means by definition that $d(u,x_2)<r_{2}$ and $d(v,x_2)<r_{2}$.

By the triangle inequality, we have:

$d(u,v) \leq d(u,x_2) + d(x_2,v) < r_{2} + r_{2} = 2 r_2$

So I have shown that $d(u,v)<2r_2$. I'd like to show that $d(u,v)>r_{1}$, but I don't think that this can be generally true (at least the way I've set up this problem).

Can some one give me a hint as to how to tackle this problem?

Comment: A possibly naive question: I would actually have thought that $r_1\leq r_2$ held. Are there examples where $r_1 > r_2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $B_{r_1}(x_1) \subset B_{r_2}(x_2)$, take $v \in B_{r_2} (x_2) \setminus B_{r_1}(x_1)$. Then, $r_1 \leq d(x_1,v)$. Ergo, $r_1 \leq d(x_1,v) \leq d(x_1,x_2) + d(x_2,v) < 2r_2$.

Perhaps this helps explain why $\leq$ is needed. Look at the points on the boundary in the picture below. $v$ could be a point on the dotted blue line.

[image]

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, but since $B_{r_1} \subset B_{r_2}$, the boundary of $B_{r_1}$ is contained in $B_{r_2}$, so it could happen that $v \in \partial B_{r_1}$. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @NoahSchweber No, read the answer. $v$ could be at the boundary of the open ball, and thus not in the ball -- just at the exact distance $r_1$.

Comment: Quite right, I misread the answer.

Comment: Can someone please explain why $r_{1} \leq d(x_{1},v)$? Is this by choice? The rest I understand.

Comment: @Greg.Paul If this wasn't the case, then $v$ would belong to $B_{r_1}(x_1)$.

Comment: @Greg.Paul Draw a picture in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for example. If $v \notin B_{r_1}$, then it does not satisfy $d(x_1,v)< r_1$. Think about the points such that $d(x_1,v)  =r_1$. These are contained in $B_{r_2}$, so you could very well choose one of these points. See the picture in the edit.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks!