# Nested open balls in a metric space: upper bounds on radii relationships

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

It is a relatively well-known fact (for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1445782/a-question-about-an-open-ball-contained-within-another-open-ball)) that if we have two nested open balls $B(a_1;r_1)\subsetneq B(a_2;r_2)$, we arise at the inequality $r_1<2r_2$.

What I don't understand is, why is $2$ the least upper bound for the ratio of $r_2$ to $r_1$ in general? As in, suppose we have a real number $a\in (1,2)$. Why isn't it true that $r_1<ar_2$ in general?

My intuition tells me that $r_1$ should be less than $r_2$ (since one ball is *contained in* the other), but this is a geometric intuition and I understand I should probably try to understand this from the axioms of a metric space. I want to try to find a metric space $(X,d)$ and use the triangle inequality to show that $r_1>(2-\varepsilon)r_2$ for arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$. Even a specific case (say, $r_1>1.99r_2$) would help. Are there any metrics that do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X:=(-1 ,1)$ the   metric space with metric induced from the usual one. With $a_2:=0$ and $r_2:=1$ we have $X=B(a_2 ,r_2)$. Let $a_1:=-1+\varepsilon$ with $0<\varepsilon<1$ and $r_1:=2-2\varepsilon$. Then $B(a_1,r_1)\subsetneq B(a_2,r_2)$ since $B(a_1,r_1)=(-1,1-\varepsilon)$.

Comment: Nice! In general, should I just restrict the space itself? Are there any examples of a distance function $d$ which makes something like this happen for all of, say, $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Let $\varphi\colon\mathbb{R}\to(-1,1)$ be defined by $\varphi(x):=\frac{x}{1+\vert x\vert}$. Then $\varphi$ is a bijection and $d$ defined by $d(x,y):=\vert \varphi(x)-\varphi(y)\vert$ is a metric for $\mathbb{R}$ which does the job.